# How can I rename after using groupby().agg()?

Tags: python, pandas

The fucntion I used is:

```
bilateral.groupby(["name_d", "year", "regime_origin"]).agg({"FLOW":"sum" ,"GDP_d":["min"]}).reset_index()
```

Then names become:

[('name_d', ''),
('year', ''),
('regime_origin', ''),
('FLOW', 'sum'),
('GDP_d', 'min')]

Sadly I cannot rename using this code:

```
bilateral.rename(columns={"('name_d', '')":"name_d", "('year', '')":"year",
                         "('regime_origin', '')":"regime_origin",
                         "('FLOW', 'sum')":"FLOW",
                "('GDP_d', 'min')":"GDP_d"}, inplace=True)
```

Comment: you don't want the keys to be strings. they are tuples (e.g., `"('name_d', '')"` should be `('name_d', '')`

Comment: I changed liek that:  columns={('name_d', ''):"name_d", ('year', ''):"year",
                         ('regime_origin', ''):"regime_origin",
                         ('FLOW', 'sum'):"FLOW",
                ('GDP_d', 'min'):"GDP_d"}. But still it does not work.

Comment: "does not work" could mean many things. please elaborate and edit the question to include a reproducible example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can to pass a dict like that:

```
.rename(columns={'old_col_name': 'new_col_name'})

# multiple cols:
.rename(columns={'old_col_name': 'new_col_name',
                 'old_col_name2': 'new_col_name2'})
```

Instead of renaming, you can also write your .agg() function like that and rename in one step:

```
.agg(columns=('old_col_name', 'aggfunc'))

# multiple cols:
.agg(new_col_name=('old_col_name', 'aggfunc'),
     new_col_name2=('old_col_name2', 'aggfunc2'))
```